# Looping through json in email - impossible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, json, ssjs, gtl

This nested Guide Template Language snippet
brings me 6 rows of titles.
Problem: I have a complex layout in an email and I want to 
populate it with titles in different places.

I can not make a simple design, like a list, to loop and populate.
So I guess I somehow need to assign each of the six {{title}}
as a value to a ampscript variable like @title1 - @title6

How can I do that?

```
%%[
var @json
set @json = HttpGET("https://example.com")
]%%


{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 6}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "@json" }
{{/data}}


{{.datasource items type=nested maxRows = 6}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "JsonVar.items" }
{{/data}}

Title: {{title}}<br>

{{/datasource}}
{{/datasource}}
```

The upper part of the json looks like this:

```
[ { "id":"123", "title":"Titlename", "component":"default", "items":[ { "title":"TitleAgain", "assetId":456, "asset":{ "id":345, "categoryId":789, "images":{ "portrait":[ { "width":189
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ServerSide Javascript in emails. Place this code at the top of the page.

This code will loop through the JSON and create (and set) the variables to be available in Ampscript.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var json = '[ { "id":"123", "title":"Titlename1" }, { "id":"456", "title":"Titlename2" }, { "id":"789", "title":"Titlename3" } ]';

// Parse JSON
var jsonObject = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(json);
var list = jsonObject;

// Loop through all items in the list (JSON)
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var listItem = list[i];

    // Set List item info
    var id = listItem['id'];
    var title = listItem['title'];

    // Set variabele name
    var loopNr = (i+1); // Add 1 because loop starts at 0
    var variableName = ("@title"+loopNr); // Combine word title with number of loop

    // Write variabele to AMPscript for further processing
    Platform.Variable.SetValue(variableName, title);
}
</script>

<h1>Available in AMPscript:</h1>
Title 1: %%=v(@title1)=%% <br />
Title 2: %%=v(@title2)=%% <br />
Title 3: %%=v(@title3)=%% <br />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need your help @Wesley

Comment: Where do you need help with?

Comment: for parsing Json @Wesley

Comment: please come here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63968/discussion-between-jjshhs-and-caspar-harmer @Wesley

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Server Side Javascript,

```
    <script runat=server>
     Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1")
     var myJson = HTTP.Get('https://my.url.service');
     //your json is an array so myJson[0]
     var title = myJson[0].title;//or maybe myJson[0]['title']
    [...]
    </script>
```

Comment: Is that recommended in an email?

Comment: I managed this by using a combination of GTL and ampscript

Answer (score 0):

A little thread necromancy, now Ampscript started supporting JSON parsing.
Given JSON format of:

```json
{
  "Flights": [
    {
      "Origin": "IND",
      "Dest": "NYC",
      "Price": 100.0
    },
    {
      "Origin": "IND",
      "Dest": "LAX",
      "Price": 200.0
    },
    {
      "Origin": "IND",
      "Dest": "SEA",
      "Price": 500.0,
      "PerBagSurcharge": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

You can now use BuildRowsetFromJson to parse it, without the need for SSJS or GTL:

```ampscript
BuildRowsetFromJson(@json, '$.Flights[*]', 1)
```

This will create a rowset with following data:

[image]

Gortonington has written a [nice article on this topic](https://gortonington.com/how-buildrowsetfromjson-can-make-your-life-so-much-better/).